# jquery selector - all elements instead with given second class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have written jquery code and html like this:

```
$("#bottom_images li").mouseenter(function() {          
        $(this).find("span").animate({bottom:0},500);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).find("span").animate({bottom:-70},500);
    });


<ul id="bottom_images">
    <li class="img1 img_active"><span>Text</span></a>
    <li class="img2"><span>Text</span></a>
    ....
</ul>
```

This code works fine (it create .animate effect on span inside li element).

But I do not need this effect for li element with class .img_active. This element has two classes img1 and img_active. I was not able to create selector that excludes li.img_active. Probably, :not should be used, but I have problems with syntax.

Comment: `$('#bottom_images li:not(.img_active)').mouseenter()`

Comment: You're right, `:not()` should be used. Did you try looking at the jQuery API? Have a read of: [`:not()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), or the [`not()` method](http://api.jquery.com/not/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change:

```
$("#bottom_images li")
```

to

```
$("#bottom_images li:not(.img_active)")
```

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, you should use `not()` jQuery selector.

```
$("#bottom_images li:not(.img_active)").mouseenter(function() {          
    $(this).find("span").animate({bottom:0},500);
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find("span").animate({bottom:-70},500);
});
```

Also, read [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).

### `:not() Selector`

> Selects all elements that **do not** match the given selector.